# Obtaining exact output values of SMO based classification, before clearly demarcating them into classes

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, weka

While running the SMO classifier in weka, if I have inputted my training labels as 0 and 5, (A binary set), then while running the classifier model on test data, are the outputs some decimal values between 0 and 5 which get distinctly classified into the two binary labels at a latter step, or are there no intermediate decimal values?

If they exist, how to obtain these intermediate decimal values?

(Eg, In the above model, does the smo/svm classifier assign values like 1 , 2, 3 and 4, or some other decimal/float value within the given range and then these get appropriately grouped under the 0 and 5 value classes).

Comment: It depends on weka, what kind of assumptions are made with your data-input, but it i'm **pretty sure**, that it just recognizes, that your data consists of two classes. Then your labels don't matter. The output values just describe the distance to the next support-vector (near class A or near class B). The idea you mention sounds more like a regression model, which is completely different from  classification! If you are using more than two classes, there are *direct multi-class formulations (crammer-singer)*, but usually a one-vs-rest / one-vs-all approach is used->multiple distances combined